# Best way to reduce urls bots have indexed

Tags: php, resources, web-crawler, bots

Google, bing and other web search engines have tons of uris in their indexes my site does not contain.  Let's say something like **http://www.mydomain.com?key=apple+banana+orange** .

Despite there is no direct link to this uri in my site, it displays a good page according to my own search engine results. (php, mysql and other stuff). The problem is that bots are eating my server resources because of heavy access spidering thousands and thousands of uris like that one. Even worst, there are indexed lot of odd strings (cannot say words).  All this is lowering performance and (I suspect) lowering site ranking.

I only want to keep all those that really exist as links in my site like

- **http://www.mydomain.com?key=apple** or
- **http://www.mydomain.com?key=banana** or
- **http://www.mydomain.com?key=orange** (one simple word key)

  and remove the others (the combinations, like the first uri).

I have created a google sitemap a year ago.

I need a solution according to google rules. The only thing I have in mind is
      `if(strstr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],'+')` then redirect to index.php
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you have your index page look at the query string and return a 404 Not Found for `key`'s that don't actually exist, that should get them out of the index.  Redirecting can be an indication that the URLs are actually valid.

Comment: I know they are all still valid, they are really 'valid'. The script checks for the query string containing 'key=' and performs an internal search with this or those words. Results can be empty but some alternatives might be displayed or, in the worst case 'No results found'. A redirect to 404.php is treated as 'soft' 404 by google apps.  I don't know if finally these uris will be removed.

Comment: And for the records, I found that google bots still tries to access files do not exist since 2005.  Those are real 404 errors

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "robots.txt" file to give instructions about your site to web robots.

You can read about how to set it up [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

**Edit**

Google talks about robots.txt as well [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&from=35237&rd=1).

Comment: Mmmmm.Maybe Disallow: /*+ and some arrangements (I don't want other query strings containing '+' to be skipped)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, I can think of, to attack this issue:
1. create a sitemap.xml (google it)
2.  Open an account in google webmaster tool: http://www.google.com/webmasters/ and claim ownership (5 mins process). 
after you're verified as the website owner, login your webmaster account, go to: 
**site configuration -> sitelinks**
and there you'll have the option to demote specific links you want google to ignore.

Comment: I had pointed out that I have created a site map a year ago. And I cannot detail all of excluded uris (maybe millions, the sum of combinations of 50.000 taken by 2, 3, 4, etc. and all sort of odd strings)